# Diagnosing mint plant with yellow spots on leaves

Tags: fungus, mint, mold

Can anyone help me to diagnose this problem of yellow spots on the leaves of my mint plant?

[image: Mint with yellow discolouration on leaves]

From googling the issue, I'm relatively sure that the answer is overwatering, underwatering, too much sun, not enough sun, nutrient deficiency, over fertilization, bad soil, pests, mildew, mold, or fungus.

But... it's hard to take action on a "diagnosis" that broad.

My first guess is overwatering, because we've had lots of rain recently. But I'm not so confident that I'm right.

Comment: Not a sun or water issue. Mint loves wet shade. And grows in full sun. Slugs or chewing insects are biting into the leaves, too. Iron deficiency? Whatever you add, dilute heavily first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm relatively new to gardening and have not seen this on a mint plant - but if what I have been taught is correct I believe the problem is a piercing insect - eg a leafhopper.  (I'm not saying it is a leafhopper though - only its a piercing insect of some sort - if there are spider webs it could be a spider mite.  ).

There is also caterpillar damage where the plant has been eaten away.

I say this because the leaves appear to be damaged in patches - and piercing insects like leafhoppers pierce the leaves to suck the liquid from the xylem  and leave damage beneath the skin of the leaf.

I don't believe it is underwatering or overwatering - these are generaly indicated by a lack of turgidity (rigidness) of the plant, and are not generally spotted.     Similarly, if it were a nutrient issue it would generally have a pattern - eg yellowing from edges or around the veins of the plant.  It is not a mildew or mold because that presents as a powdery loo on the leaves.     There is an outside chance a fungus is present as there is some curling of leaves, but it does not look significant to me and I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll try neem oil to control the pests. I'll let you know how it goes.